Cannon Ball shot on moving Target.
A Cannon Ball is shot, with velocity $v=250 \frac{m}{s}$ from the point $(0,50)$ at some angle $\theta$. When the Ball is shot the target is at the Point $(500,0)$. The target moves with the Speed of $v'=5\frac{m}{s}$ in x direction.So the target is at $(500+v'\cdot t,0)$ at Time t.My goal is to calculate the angle $\theta$ at which the Ball needs to be shot to hit the target.
The movement of the Ball in x direction is given as $x(t)=\cos(\theta)\cdot v \cdot t$
In y direction as $y(t)=50+\sin(\theta)\cdot v \cdot t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$
We can calculate t dependent of $\theta$ as $t=\frac{500}{250\cos(\theta)-5}$
We then have $0=50 + 250 \cdot \sin(\theta) \cdot \frac{500}{250\cos(\theta)-5}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot 9.81 \cdot (\frac{500}{250\cos(\theta)-5})^2$
And thats the Point where im stuck. I have trouble solving the last Equation. If anyone knows how to do it or knows a more simple approach for the Problem i appreciate your help.

Is this exercise "home-made"?  Do you have any reason to believe this can be solved with pen and paper without approximations? Maybe guess and check angles like $45^{\circ}$ (which typically maximizes range in projectile motion). and then back substitute to find $t$

Shouldn't $\cos(\theta)-5$ be $250\cos(\theta)-5$?

Yeah sorry @David K

@Anthony i solved the same problem without the target moving and wanted to try to solve it with the moving target. So no im not sure it can be solved by hand
